# Doubt on how I have applied Newton's law of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, relative-motion

I have found several questions where the pseudo force is applied in the wrong direction, and I am confused whether I m correct or not. The question is something like this.

> Thin threads are tightly wound on the ends of a uniform solid cylinder of mass $m$. The free ends of the threads are attached to the ceiling of an elevator car. The car starts going up with an acceleration $\vec{w_0}$. Find the force $\vec{F}$ exerted by the cylinder on the ceiling (through the threads).

For an observer inside the lift the effective gravity acting of the body should be $g+ \vec{w_o}$. (due to pseudo force) and not $g- \vec{w_o}$ as the lift is going up. Pseudo force acts opposite to the motion of the accelerated frame.

According to me answer should be $$F=\dfrac { 1 }{ 3 } m(g+{\omega}_{o} )\quad $$ everything I did is same as given below just the direction of pseudo force is different.

The solution that was given is :-

> If the observer is in the elevator the gravitational force as 
>   observed by the observer will be =$$m(g-{w}_{o})$$
>   where $g$ = acceleration due to gravity
>   $ {w}_{o} $ = acceleration of the elevator.
>   From Newton's Laws :
>    $$ m(g-{w}_{o})-2T=ma .....(1)$$a = acceleration of the cylinder relative to the car (because the observer is in the car he will see relative motion)
>   As slipping is not there:
>   $$ I\alpha =2Tr\\ \dfrac { 1 }{ 2 } mr^ 2\times \dfrac { a }{ r } =2Tr\\ T=\dfrac { ma }{ 4 } $$
>   Substitutung the value of T in equation (1)
>    $$ m(g-{w}_{o})-\dfrac { ma }{ 2 } =ma $$
>   on solving we get
>   $$ \dfrac { 3ma }{ 2 } =  m(g-{w}_{o})$$
>   or a=$$\dfrac { 2 }{ 3 } (g-{w}_{o})$$
>   Force exerted by the cylinder on the ceiling of the elevator =2T
>   using the value of T from above which is also equal to $$ \dfrac { ma }{ 4 } $$
>   Substituting the value of "a" from above and solving
>   $$ 2T=\dfrac { ma }{ 2 } \\ a=\frac { 2 }{ 3 } (g-{\omega}_{o} )\\ 2T=\dfrac { m\dfrac { 2 }{ 3 } (g-{\omega}_{o} ) }{ 2 } \\ 2T=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } m(g-{\omega}_{o} )\quad or\\ F=\dfrac { 1 }{ 3 } m(g-{\omega}_{o} )\quad $$

Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to consider is what is meant by force $\vec F = F \,\hat x$ and $\vec F = -F \,\hat x$ in diagram below.

[image]

If force $\vec F = F \,\hat x$, then $F$ is the component of force $\vec F$ in the $\hat x$ direction and the component can either can have either a positive or negative numerical value and in this case $F=-10$.

$\vec F = -F \,\hat x$ is often used so that $F$ turns out to be be a positive quantity ie is the magnitude of the vector.

In terms of components you can interpret $\vec F = -F \,\hat x$  in two ways:
    $\vec F = (-F) \,\hat x$ and (-F) is the component of $\vec F$ in the $\hat x$ direction.
$\vec F = F \,(-\hat x)$ and $F$ is the component of $\vec F$ in the $(-\hat x)$ direction
and in both cases $F=10$ which in this case is the magnitude of the vector.

If the direction of the vector is known a positive numerical value rather than a negative numerical value for $F$ is often favoured.

---

Initially I will assume that the frame of reference is the Earth and the cylinder is not accelerating relative to the elevator car ie its acceleration is $\vec{\omega_0}$ (up).

Applying Newton's second law gives $\vec F + m \vec g = m \vec{\omega_0}$
This a vector equation and the only direction which has been fixed is the $\hat z$ direction which is up.

There are two ways (actually four depending on the numerical values of $\omega_0$ and $g$) of solving the problem.

$F \hat z + (-g) \hat z = m \omega_0 \hat z \Rightarrow F - mg = m\omega_0 \Rightarrow F = m(\omega_0+g)$
Doing it this way you would need to substitute (+9.8) for $g$ into the equation.

$F \hat z + (g) \hat z = m \omega_0  \hat z \Rightarrow F + mg = m\omega_0 \Rightarrow F = m(\omega_0-g)$
Doing it this way you would need to substitute (-9.8) for $g$ into the equation.

---

Now consider what happens if the frame of reference is the elevator car which is accelerating upwards at $\vec{\omega_0}$ relative to the Earth.

In this frame the cylinder and thread are at rest (not accelerating) and so a pseudo force of $m  \vec{\omega_0}$ in a downward direction is added so that Newton's laws can be used.

$\vec F + m \vec g + m \vec {\omega_0} = m \vec 0$

Knowing that both $m\vec g$ and $m\vec \omega_0$ both act downwards I would write $F \hat z +mg(-\hat z) + m\omega_0(-\hat z)= 0 \Rightarrow F = m(\omega_0+g)$ as before with the numerical values of $a$ and $\omega_0$ both being positive.

There are three other equivalent equation which could be derive depending on the sign that you give the numerical values of $g$ and $\omega_o$.

---

And then you have not got the final answer as $\vec F = m(\omega_0+g) \hat z$ is the force on the cylinder and threads due to the elevator car.
You were asked for the force on the elevator car due to the threads (and the cylinder) and that is $m(\omega_0+g) (-\hat z)$ or $-m(\omega_0+g) \hat z$

---

You can adapt what I have written if the cylinder is accelerating elative to the elevator car.

Answer (score 0):

You are both right. It is just a sign issue. In both solutions you are adding two **positive** figures  within the parentheses.

Strictly speaking, the book is more accurate because $g$ and $\omega_0$ do point to opposite directions.

Comment: Thank you so so much. It's should be $\vec{g}-\vec{w_o}$ bcoz $\vec{g}$ and $\vec{w_o}$ are in opposite direction. So when I consider the magnitude it will be $g-(-w_o)$ i.e. $g+w_o$. I m correct in terms of magnitude but incorrect in terms of direction.